# What is the solution for this error ' the instraller can't partion on the disk while installing lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, disk, boot-partition

When installing Lubuntu, I get an error, how do I fix this?

[image]

```
Error

Installation Failed

The instaler failed to create partition on disk 'ST50OLMO12 HN-M500MBB

===z*s*==asas*
=s======= =====s
Create a new partition (10,74 GiB. fat32) on /dev/sda'
==z==z=====s==z===ss==s======
==ss=s===a===============zz=*
Job: Create new partition on device /dev/sda'*
============s===ss=====* =======* ==*
E==s: ===*
Command: sfdisk-force-append /dev/sda asasaaasaaaa-=
=======s=======z=zsz=zsz=zz=a=====
Failed to add partition 'New Partition' to device /dev/sda'. Failed to add partition 'New Partition' to device dev/sda.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [Lubuntu 20.04 (*focal*) release notes](https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/) you'll find

> Installs replacing a partition may fail with [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/calamares/+bug/1864787). As a
> workaround; reboot, use KDE Partition Manager to delete the ‘unknown’
> partition that exists, create the partition using the format you want
> (ext4, btrfs were tested & worked), deactivate swap partitions & exit
> KDE Partition Manager. Calamares can then use the prepared partition.

That condition deals with

> sfdisk --force --append /dev/sda

Comment: FYI: we tested XFS too even if not mentioned in release notes.

Comment: Please also see https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/calamares-rare-failure-to-create-partition-mkfs-errors/2774